# Magento 2 get hidden image programmatically

Tags: php, product-attribute, magento2.3.2, media-images

I have a custom module for exporting links of my product images.

With this code:

```
public function getImageAttributes()
    {
        $attributes = [
            'thumbnail' => 'Thumbnail',
            'image' => 'Base Image',
            'small_image' => 'Small Image',
        ];

        return $this->customizeArray($attributes, ExportProduct::PREFIX_IMAGE_ATTRIBUTE);
    }
```

I have the option to choose which image(thumb or base or small) to call

And with this code:

```
public function getGalleryAttributes()
    {
        $attributes = [
            'image_1' => 'Image 1',
            'image_2' => 'Image 2',
            'image_3' => 'Image 3',
            'image_4' => 'Image 4',
            'image_5' => 'Image 5',
        ];

        return $this->customizeArray($attributes, ExportProduct::PREFIX_GALLERY_ATTRIBUTE);
    }
```

I have set another option if I want to take links by images place(slot 1,2 etc.)

I want to do the same but with **hidden images** of my products.

To call the link of the hidden image only

Any help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can get all media images including hidden images from below code.

First load single product from collection then use blow getData method to get all images.

It will return with disable = 1 like.

```php
$product->getData('media_gallery');

Array
(
   [14576] => Array
   (
   [value_id] => 14576
   [file] => /m/a/mad-angle_6.jpg
   [media_type] => image
   [entity_id] => 5417
   [label] =>
   [position] => 1
   [disabled] => 0
   [label_default] =>
   [position_default] => 1
   [disabled_default] => 0
   [video_provider] =>
   [video_url] =>
   [video_title] =>
   [video_description] =>
   [video_metadata] =>
   [video_provider_default] =>
   [video_url_default] =>
   [video_title_default] =>
   [video_description_default] =>
   [video_metadata_default] =>
   )

   [19689] => Array
   (
   [value_id] => 19689
   [file] => /s/a/salt-pepper_29_1.jpg
   [media_type] => image
   [entity_id] => 5417
   [label] =>
   [position] => 2
   [disabled] => 1
   [label_default] =>
   [position_default] => 2
   [disabled_default] => 1
   [video_provider] =>
   [video_url] =>
   [video_title] =>
   [video_description] =>
   [video_metadata] =>
   [video_provider_default] =>
   [video_url_default] =>
   [video_title_default] =>
   [video_description_default] =>
   [video_metadata_default] =>
   )

   [19690] => Array
   (
   [value_id] => 19690
   [file] => /s/o/soup-bowl-purple-verbena_3_1.jpg
   [media_type] => image
   [entity_id] => 5417
   [label] =>
   [position] => 3
   [disabled] => 1
   [label_default] =>
   [position_default] => 3
   [disabled_default] => 1
   [video_provider] =>
   [video_url] =>
   [video_title] =>
   [video_description] =>
   [video_metadata] =>
   [video_provider_default] =>
   [video_url_default] =>
   [video_title_default] =>
   [video_description_default] =>
   [video_metadata_default] =>
   )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this method - First load the product collection then use getMediaGalleryEntries function to get images details.

```
$this->_productRepository = $this->objectManager->create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface::class);
       $product = $this->_productRepository->get($sku);
    
 $img = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
 $hiddenImage = [];
 foreach ($img as $image) {
     if ($image->getDisabled() == '1') {
             $hiddenImage[] =  $image->getFile();
     }
 }
```